# Launchd to terminate what it starts

Tags: launchd

I have a launchd plist that uses StartCalendarInterval to start my python script at the desired time and day of the week.

Now I want to create a launchd plist that both starts and terminates a different python script at selected times.    Where is the "KillCalender" command or equivalent?

Essentially, I want the program the controls my Christmas lights come on at 1800 and go off at 2200.

I suppose I could write the main loop in my python program so it terminates at 2200 but I was hoping launchd could do this for me.

Comment: Does python need to run whilst the lights are on or just to turn them on and off

Comment: Yes, python would be running the whole time to blink things, switch colors etc.

Comment: I would write an app to message your app - launchd would run the new app at 2200

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the [ExitTimeOut value](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) for `launchd.plist`:

> **TimeOut**
>
> The recommended idle time out (in seconds) to pass to the job. If no value is specified, a default time out will be supplied by launchd for use by the job at check in time.
>
> **ExitTimeOut**
>
> The amount of time launchd waits before sending a SIGKILL signal. The default value is 20 seconds. The value zero is interpreted as infinity.

Comment: FWIW, the man page description of `TimeOut` now includes the note "This key never did anything interesting and is no longer implemented".